# How can I use libgdx BitmapFont draw method to write text of specific font style and size.

Tags: fonts, libgdx

I have tried the code given below:

```
Assets.font.draw(objspritebatch, chooseBackground, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*.5f,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*.5f);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to draw text, it's probably in the game's HUD or in the menus. Then you should check out [scene2d](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d), and especially the [scene2d.ui widget *Label*](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui#Label). And don't forget to explore [the API](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/index.html?com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/package-summary.html).

However, to simply draw text on the screen, check out [this wiki article](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/addingText2D). If you want to use your own custom font, you will need to package it with [Hiero](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Hiero).